# Are Top Fans available in the YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api

Is information about [Top Fans](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3265949?hl=en) somehow available via YouTube API? I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not available as of now. But you can [create a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Enhancement%20Request)